# How to Animate Water drops on Surface

Tags: particles

Does anyone have an idea on how to animate water drops on a surface and let them be blown away by air?
Just like in the Video.

https://mega.nz/file/xPgB0LTb#HslDr69x6KY9ujpo8UA4JAx7j_awlvG5p7UGO4VVGsE

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.